# Importing variable from another module results in AttributeError

Tags: python, python-2.7

when I try to print the value of `var1` I get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'var1'` I've researched for hours and some answers mention de creation of Classes, I guess there might be a simpler solution:

This is the main script

```
#script.py
from module1 import function1
from module2 import function2

function1(arg) #It calls the function and works fine

print function1.var1 #HERE IT BREAKS WITH THE AttributeError!

function2(otherArgs) #I suppose this will also break...
```

Here is the first module

```
#module1.py
def function1(args1):
    #some stuff
    var1 = 'some'
```

Here the second which also calls `var1`

```
#module2.py
import module1
def function2(args2):
    #some stuff
    print module1.var1
```

Comment: If `var1` is defined inside the function it will be local to that function. the syntax you are trying to use is for `OOP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions act like black boxes, so all variables inside the function are only used in the calculation of the final result. Once the function is finished, it returns any results you tell it to, and then deletes all the local variables. I think what you are trying to do should look more like this:

```
#module1.py
def function1(args1):
    #some stuff
    var1 = 'some'
    return var1

#script.py
from module1 import function1
from module2 import function2

var1 = function1(arg) #It calls the function and works fine

print var1

function2(otherArgs)
```

Attributes are only for classes, a function keeps nothing after running except what you tell it to return and any global variables which were modified during the execution of the function.